# Reference android.target.classpath not found

Tags: android, ant, build

I'm working on an Ant script for an Android build, but am coming up against the error

**Reference android.target.classpath not found**

I can't find any information on what android.target.classpath is or where it is set.  Does anyone know?

Comment: it is in buit android.jar file class information.not your bug.it is good habit to find bug from logcat

Comment: I'll take a look at my path declarations, I must have messed something up.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You may want to reconsider awarding your acceptance to ge0rg - his answer offers a workable solution to this problem.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

it is in buit android.jar file class information.not your bug.it is good habit to find bug from logcat

Comment: This answer isn't very useful. My build.xml tries to reference this in several places, and now my build is broken. Is there something we should replace this with? Delete the reference? A bit more description would be useful.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 29):

With SDK revision 20, the new name of former `android.target.classpath` is  `project.target.class.path`.

It must be really funny for Android engineers to break the build.xml API with every release.

Comment: That IS ridiculous. Just for a better property name? Sheesh.

Comment: If you want to use this variable in your custom target, add this attribute to the target element: `depends="-set-debug-mode,-build-setup"`